# Add a Controller to a Laravel 5 Package

Tags: php, laravel

Lately, I've been creating only models for my L5 packages, but now I'd like to try and introduce a Controller as well. I've been following [this](http://prosperotemuyiwa.com/2015/05/08/creating-your-first-laravel-5-package/) but I always get the error `"Class StatController does not exist"`.

Folder structure

```
/src
    routes.php
    /Controllers
        StatController.php
```

StatController.php

```
<?php namespace Enchance\Sentrysetup\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class StatController extends Controller {

    public function index() {
        return 'Moot.';
    }

}
```

Service provider

```
public function register()
{
    // Can't get this to work
    include __DIR__.'/routes.php';
    $this->app->make('Enchance\Sentrysetup\Controllers\StatController');

    $this->app['sentrysetup'] = $this->app->share(function($app) {
        return new Sentrysetup;
    });
}
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('slap', 'StatController@index');
```

Does anyone have an alternate way of assigning a Controller to a L5 package?

Comment: Try to put fully qualified name in your routes and `$this->app->make('\Enchance\Sentrysetup\Controllers\StatController');`

Comment: No, that didn't work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't need to call `$this->app->make()` on your controllers. Controllers are resolved by Laravel's IoC automatically (meaning that Laravel creates / instantiates controllers automatically that are tied to routes).

Require your routes in the `boot()` method of your packages service provider:

```
public function boot()
{
    require __DIR__.'/routes.php';     
}
```

And inside your `routes.php` file:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Enchance\Sentrysetup\Controllers'], function()
{
    Route::get('slap', ['uses' => 'StatController@index']);
})
```

Also, just a tip. You should [PascalCase](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PascalCase) your namespaces:

```
Enchance\SentrySetup\Controllers
```

*Note the capital S in setup*

The `boot()` method should be used to register your routes because when Laravel starts up, it goes through each service provider in your `config/app.php` file, creates them, calls the `register()` method (to insert/add any dependencies that the service provider "provides" into Laravel's singleton / IoC container).

Think of Laravel's container as simply a big key => value array. Where the "key" is the name of the dependency (such as `config`), and the "value" is a closure (`function () {}`) that is called to create the dependency:

```php
// Exists as a property inside the Container:
$bindings = [
    "config" => function () {
        // Create the application configuration.
    }
];

// Create the app configuration.
$config = $bindings['config']();

// Create the app configuration (Laravel).
$config = app()->make('config');
```

Once Laravel has registered each provider, it then goes through them again and calls the `boot()` method. This ensures that any dependencies that have been registered (inside of the `register()` method of all of your application service providers) is available in the `boot()` method, ready to be used.

[The Service Provider Boot Method - Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/providers#the-boot-method)

Comment: Thanks Steve! That worked perfectly. How did you know it needed a namespace in the route? Also seeing as putting the route in `boot()` also works in `register()` why is the former more preferred?

Comment: No problem! Also if you have any dependencies inside your routes file such as the Laravel translator, cache, or database etc, it ensures that all other services are registered *before* calling your service provider boot method. More information here: http://laravel.com/docs/master/providers#the-boot-method. Also, for any namespaced controllers, you need to either specify the full namespace when you register your route, or place it in a `Route::group()` with the `namespace` array option.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in controller function:

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
```

Like:

```
namespace Enchance\Sentrysetup\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

class StatController extends Controller {

    public function index() {
        return 'Moot.';
    }

}
```

And in controller:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Enchance\Sentrysetup\Controllers'], function()
{
    Route::get('slap', 'StatController@index');
});
```

In boot function:

```
public function boot()
{
    require __DIR__.'/routes.php';     
}
```